# Discord slash command 2 choices

Tags: python, discord.py, slash, coin-flipping

I coded a /coinflip command in python for my discord bot economy system. Now I can't figure out how to set two choices for the slash command so it is either head or tails.

I tried to implement the choices via defining choices = ... when using it as a ctx command, it works just fine but when using a slash command it just prints out errors or wotn even start.

```
@bot.tree.command(name="coinflip", description="Wirf eine Münze und schau was passiert!")
async def coinflip(interaction: discord.Interaction):
    userid = str(interaction.user.id)
    choices = ["kopf", "zahl"]
    botchoice = random.choice(choices)
    filename = f"database/{userid}.txt"
    if choices == botchoice:
        if os.path.isfile(filename):
            with open(filename, "r") as file:
                coins = int(file.read())
            newcoins = coins + 25
            with open(filename, "w") as file:
                file.write(str(newcoins))
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Du gewinnst 25 Münzen, da das Ergebnis {botchoice} war.", ephemeral=True)
        else:
            with open(filename, "w") as file:
                file.write("25")
            await interaction.response.send_message(f"Du gewinnst 25 Münzen, da das Ergebnis {botchoice} war.", ephemeral=True)
    else:
        await interaction.response.send_message(f"Das war wohl nix, da das Ergebnis leider {botchoice} war.", ephemeral=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if choices == botchoice:
```

On this line you are comparing choices `choices = ["kopf", "zahl"]` a list
with `botchoice = random.choice(choices)` a string

Therefore, your function will always return false
I guess what you wanted to do is something along the line of

```
if "kopf" == botchoice:
```

or

```
if "zahl" == botchoice
```

Comment: well firstly i wanted to give the user who is executing the command the option of the two choices and then look if the bot made the choice "kopf" or the choice "zahl", but that could be another problem with my code :D